# Input on Datagridview automatically

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem that I cant solve, so I need to ask

**Problem :*
I have a data grid view, and have made custom column for it. I input the data on IDB column and I hope column Name,price can automatically input in the the row, and after that I can input amount manually and the total will be amount * price

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(4) {New DataColumn("IDB", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Price", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Amount", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Total", GetType(Integer))})
Me.MetroGrid1.DataSource = dt
```

I have to input some IDB to datagridview manually and its automatically get data from mysql database, how do I do that ?

I have tried this

```
Private Sub inputdata(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MetroGrid1.CellValueChanged
        Dim dgrow As Integer = 0


        Try
            If MetroGrid1.Rows(baris).Cells("IDB").Value Then
                mysqlConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString
                mysqlConnection.Open()
                Dim bc As MySqlDataReader
                cmdmysql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM product where IDB = '" + MetroGrid1.Rows(dgrow).Cells("IDB").Value + "'"
                cmdmysql.Connection = mysqlConnection
                bc = cmdmysql.ExecuteReader
                If bc.HasRows Then
                    bc.Read()
                    MetroGrid1.Rows(dgrow).Cells("Name").Value = bc.Item(3)
                    MetroGrid1.Rows(dgrow).Cells("Price").Value = bc.Item(4)
                    Label3.Text = bc.Item(3)
                    Label4.Text = bc.Item(4)

                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

It can automatically input first data,but it say some error

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Not allowed to
>   change the 'ConnectionString' property while the connection
>   (state=Open). at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) at SCS_MetroDesign.Pembayaran.gantidata(Object sender,
>   DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) in:line 69

line 69 : mysqlConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

It doesn't error when I didn't use MetroGrid1.Rows(dgrow).Cells("Name").Value = bc.Item(3) , but without this I cant input automatically using only IDB

Please help me solving this problem, Thanks in advance

Comment: this is because the mysqlConnection u have tried giving connection string is already open.try closing mysqlConnection before changing the conection string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first save data in dataTable or dataset and then fetch data from dataTable or dataset.

Example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(bc);
```

and then use dt for fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable mysqlConnection is defined somewhere else in your project, and it's state is open from another connection. Double check you program for Mysql-connections which is not closed after use.

Or for quick fix,check by adding

`mysqlConnection.close()` before `mysqlConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString`

Hope You Got needed Input.

Comment: yeah, i have tried it before, but still error
t doesnt error when i didnt use MetroGrid1.Rows(dgrow).Cells("Name").Value = bc.Item(3) , but without this i cant input automatically using only IDB

Comment: but where actually the eexception occurs..in which line?

Comment: ok does it work for the first time run?? please show the code where you use the function input data?

Comment: i dont really get it but

when i delete MetroGrid1.Rows(dgrow).Cells("Name").Value = bc.Item(3) and put the value on label it work, but when i put the value to gridview it show error, that is what make me confuse

Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
 End Try

Comment: pls update question with code where function input data is called.and pls specify does the code work for firsttime run?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what is firsttime run mean, can you explain it for me ?

Comment: the data i input on gridview,no code called, just need to input the some id on IDB column cell, and i hope the column Name,price can automatically input in the the row, and after that i can input amount manually and the total will be amount * price

Comment: Private Sub inputdata(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MetroGrid1.CellValueChanged
, the gridview value change

Comment: first time when you change gridvalue does the exception occur?

Comment: yes, the error code is showed just like i post before

Comment: its okay, just feel to ask somebody right now, gonna put this problem behind and search for better method to do it :D